# Trouble using the Transactional annotation in groovy

Tags: hibernate, spring, groovy, annotations, transactional

Has anyone had any experience with Spring transactions (class-level, with proxy, annotation-driven) not getting started in a Groovy Class? I've been struggling with an unexplained LazyInitialization exception noticed that stacktrace does not include a call to start the transaction. Sounds crazy but I have to wonder whether Groovy picks up on the Transactional annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the source of the problem. From the Spring documentation (i added in emphasis):

> 24.5.1. AOP - advising scripted beans
>   It is possible to use the Spring AOP framework to advise scripted beans. The Spring AOP framework actually is unaware that a bean that is being advised might be a scripted bean, so all of the AOP use cases and functionality that you may be using or aim to use will work with scripted beans. **There is just one (small) thing that you need to be aware of when advising scripted beans... you cannot use class-based proxies, you must use interface-based proxies.**
>   You are of course not just limited to advising scripted beans... you can also write aspects themselves in a supported dynamic language and use such beans to advise other Spring beans. This really would be an advanced use of the dynamic language support though.

My problem was that I was using class-based proxies.

Comment: hm and can you post some example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grails, you could try using

```
MyDomainClass.withTransaction {    
  // Code within the transaction goes here
}
```

as an alternative to the transactional annotation. If the code works with this approach, then you can be sure that it's the annotation that's the cause of the problem (though I understand you may not like this as a permanent solution).